# To extract rows with matching values (SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a few thousand rows, and I would like to extract texts if there are matching values in different rows and columns.

For example:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| teeth | MrA | 123 | ABC | $128 |
| nose | MrB | CDE | 789 | $100 |
| hand | MrC | ABC | 456 | $128 |
| eye | MrD | ABC | 789 | $110 |
| eye | MrD | EFG | 789 | $110 |

The expected outcome is if any value of C = D or vice versa, and with same E value, then the query should return values from column A & column B or the whole row.

Results would be:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| teeth | MrA | 123 | ABC | $128 |
| hand | MrC | ABC | 456 | $128 |

as C matches with D on ABC and E = $128 which is same for both rows.

Also, is it possible to extract common values from column C & column D into one new column?

| A | B | C | D | E | F (New Column) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| teeth | MrA | 123 | ABC | $128 | ABC |
| hand | MrC | ABC | 456 | $128 | ABC |

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What would column E be if, in your example, 456 was replaced with 123; so that the two rows share two common value? (123 and ABC)

Comment: Sorry didn't thought of this earlier, checked through my data and there are very few rows with matching values and share two common values, but if 456 was replaced with 123, column F should take either 123 or ABC. If 1st row = 123, 2nd row should follow = 123.

Comment: What about if a third row matches? So, again using your example, if a new row was added with E=$128, C=456, D=123, what happens then?

Comment: This is similar to your previous question and requires a simple additional *and* criteria for the row elimination, however your column F criteria is far from clear and requires some additional data and a clearer description.

Comment: My apologies, correction: there wouldn't be a case where there are two common values, there will be only one common value between the two columns C&D for same E

Comment: so will your results only ever be 2 rows? Eg if the sample data had 2 of the first row *teeth* then the results will have 3 rows, `c` will have two rows of `123` and `d` will have 2 rows of `ABC`... so which appears in column `F`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not sure how column `F` should be determined (a better understanding of the data might help) however here is one option that might work - possibly it could be simplified.

After determining the qualifying rows, get the most common occuring value from `c` and `d`, then use whichever is "greater" - this criteria might need adjusting depending on your needs.

```
with x as (
    select *
        from t
    where exists (
        select * from t t2 
        where (t.c=t2.d or t.d=t2.c) and t.e=t2.e
    )
)
select a, b, c, d, e,
    Iif(cv.f > dv.f, cv.f, dv.f) f
from x
outer apply (
    select top (1) c f
    from x
    group by c
    order by Count(*) desc
)cv
outer apply (
    select top (1) d f
    from x
    group by d
    order by Count(*) desc
)dv
```